# Split string procedure can't find table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get this procedure to work and it is stumping me. I simply want this procedure to populate a temp table with the separated values from a table of CSV values.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS String_Split $$

CREATE PROCEDURE String_Split
(
    vString VARCHAR(255),
    vSeparator VARCHAR(5)
)
BEGIN

DECLARE vDone tinyint(1) DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE vIndex INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE vSubString VARCHAR(15);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpValues;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpValues (tmpVal VARCHAR(255));

WHILE vDone > 0 DO
    SET vSubString = SUBSTRING(vString, vIndex,
    IF(LOCATE(vSeparator, vString, vIndex) > 0,
        LOCATE(vSeparator, vString, vIndex) - vIndex,
        LENGTH(vString)
        ));
    IF LENGTH(vSubString) > 0 THEN
        SET vIndex = vIndex + LENGTH(vSubString) + 1;
        INSERT INTO tmpValues VALUES (vSubString);
    ELSE
        SET vDone = 0;
    END IF;
END WHILE;

END; $$
```

I call on it:

```
CALL String_Split(my_csv.keywords, ',');
```

And I get this:
    Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'my_csv' in field list

I'm not getting this because the table is there and the appropriate database is selected.

```
CREATE TABLE `my_csv` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`keywords` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 $$

INSERT INTO `my_csv` () VALUES
(1, 'featured, 3/8, Diamond, Engagement Ring, 14K, White Gold, Gold'),
(2, '1/3, Diamond, Engagement Ring, 14K, White Gold, Gold'),
(3, 'featured') $$
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the table name and field in the call function, you need to get the value first, then call the procedure. Here's a working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e9b6/12).

```sql
SELECT @keyword :=keywords from my_csv;
CALL String_Split(@keyword, ',');
```

**Edit:**
That only grabbed the last row. This [one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/042a0/1) selects all of them. Also, doing this the `vSeparator` variable in the procedure was too small, so I bumped that up to 255.

```sql
SELECT @keyword :=group_concat(keywords) FROM my_csv;
CALL String_Split(@keyword, ',');
select * from tmpValues;
```